# Insert field into dictionary at specific position, not append at end

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am reading JSON from a file and want to add **fn2** just after **fn** field, while setting video['fn2']=7 will append to end of JSON, I am using Python 3.7.9:

```
import json

# read json file
with open('myjson.json', encoding="utf-8-sig") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for video in data:
        video['fn2'] = 7;


# write data to json file
with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

this is a sample of my original json:

```
[
    {
        "fn": "f1.txt",
        "post": "11",
        "tp": "z"
    }
]
```

and this is output after append :

```
[
    {
        "fn": "f1.txt",
        "post": "11",
        "tp": "z",
        "fn2": 7
    }
]
```

but I need output to be like :

```
[
    {
        "fn": "f1.txt",
        "fn2": 7,
        "post": "11",
        "tp": "z"
    }
]
```

Comment: why?? In a (JSON-)dictionary the order of the keys is irrelevant

Comment: Dictionaries are always sorted by insertion order, so if you want to change the order you will need to insert all the entries into a new dict.

Comment: You could use `OrderedDict` or `dict(sorted(video.items()))`

Comment: @rioV8 The JSON spec actually leaves it somewhat ambiguous. The suggested idea is that objects should be considered unordered and not contain duplicates, however, that is implementation dependent. ["JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling software.  Implementations whose behavior does not depend on member ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be affected by these differences."](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-4)

Comment: In this case in particular, since your expected output is alphabetical, you could also pass `sort_keys=True` to `json.dumps`

Comment: continuing.. the Python standard library implementation of JSON assumes that keys have no strict ordering, and that there are no duplicates. If you require these semantics, Python is fundamentally incompatible for the use-case in how JSON objects are unmashalled as Python objects. In that case, you should choose different tooling which can meet your needs, which most likely would not be implemented in Python.

Comment: IMO if you are using an object and yet you want ordering of the key-value pairs you are using the wrong data structure and should go for arrays instead.

Answer (score 2):

With the [`object_pairs_hook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) option of `json.loads` you can customize the initialization of a dict object given a sequence of tuples of key-value pairs by using a dict subclass that inserts a particular key-value pair immediately after a specified key:

```
import json

def insert_key_value_after_key(key, value, after_key):
    class DictKeyAfterKey(dict):
        def __init__(self, key_value_pairs):
            for k, v in key_value_pairs:
                self[k] = v
                if k == after_key:
                    self[key] = value
    return DictKeyAfterKey

data = json.loads('''[
    {
        "fn": "f1.txt",
        "post": "11",
        "tp": "z"
    }
]''', object_pairs_hook=insert_key_value_after_key('fn2', 7, 'fn'))
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

This outputs:

```
[
    {
        "fn": "f1.txt",
        "fn2": 7,
        "post": "11",
        "tp": "z"
    }
]
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHbasMwDH3PV4i8xAFTyDbYKORhsLd9QinGa2zqJrWNrZRlY9@eyd5ouhYm8EVHR0ey7CfcO3v/5MM8m6N3AeEQnS2KTmkwNqqAoleTOMlhVEJqVCH5jBaHDHI4o/W6ALLdIGOEF7PDVzU9pyCdrCP/l5As6QthrEEhWFSD5rDU8dKEeEFOpl2AnmpSV9fMv8RkSXDTb6GF003MaOihbZe2b9MXCTVlkVQrs4LCMdjrx9G4JEoiptmtBie7yKqq2uSUz7N8qW25pr1Z4TuWfMG9i5giTXOJok/YR5mRr2JLihzc20Ht8OfdYu9c3/7zS5W2d5TzyIFuVV0XPhiLLHfZjUcfWeqb00g7ZbF9qOt5/gY)